# ComboBox Selected Item or ComboBox text Which you prefer to get the Combo Box Value in WinForm C#?

Tags: mysql, winforms

[image]

When i saw the Combo box Propriety Selected item and text Returns Same value in WinForms.

So What is Difference  in between,.. Where i use ComboBox.SelectedItem ?
and Where i use ComboBox.Text?

Comment: combobox.Text is the displayed text, seledted item is the current selected item. be carefull when doing a combobox.selecteditem_changed, i am not sure if combobox.text is updated before handeling the event

Answer (score 0):

You can put any object to the ComboBox control.

- SelectedItem will return this object.
- Text will return string representation of the SelectedItem when ComboBoxStyle = DropDownList ( text portion is not editable), the result may be like this - SelectedItem.ToString().

Find more information here - [ComboBox Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx).

In your case, if you add strings into the ComboBox.Items, then there is no difference what to use SelectedItem or Text.

Comment: SelectedText is not the case, its combobox.Text

Comment: Ya combobox.Text or ComboBox.SelectedItem What I prefer?

Comment: It is on your choice; agree with Moonlight notes about cast to string. Note, when text is editable, Text string can differ from (string)SelectedItem; because you can set Text property.

Answer (score 0):

combobox.text is always a string, combobox.selectedItem is an object

Comment: if you want to use them all as strings, you can use .Text so you dont have to parse an object to a string (.ToString() method)